# Node js app does not reply API calls because web socket is using all resources

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm using web sockets (`ws` module) for getting data from a server. Something around 1000 messages per second are received, processed, and then broadcast (on `ws` again) to my clients.

In the meantime, I keep the statistics of incoming and outgoing messages and update them on the time of receiving/sending messages.

On the other hand, I have written a couple of `Get` methods so that I can monitor the server and get statistics.

The problem I am facing is that the web-socketing part of the application works totally smooth, but the `Get` methods are not responding well at all times; sometimes they reply with delay, sometimes they take forever to reply.

How can I tell `node` to do this right for me? How can I make my Get methods as IMPORTANT and RESPONSIVE at all times? Do I need multi-threading? Do I need to use multiple cores of CPU?

I'm clueless in this situation and need your experience.

Comment: You can't do multi-threading using nodejs but you can use several processes

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this @Vivick? Would that solve the issue? Will I be right to say "each process has its own slice of CPU time this way, hence the methods will be responsive"?

Comment: Not necessarily, first you need to pin down why exactly there's a delay, once this is done you can try to see if using multiple processes would solve your problem

Comment: Note that [clusters](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) might help you too